# Increment dates based on original start date

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set

```
dt <- data.table(Customer = c("a", "a","b","b"), months = c(2,2,2,3), Date = c("2014-03-1","2015-10-1","2015-01-1","2016-01-1"), Cost = c("100","200","50","20"))
```

```
   Customer months      Date Cost
1:        a      2 2014-03-1  100
2:        a      2 2015-10-1  200
3:        b      2 2015-01-1   50
4:        b      3 2016-01-1   20
```

I am looking to repeat each row by number of months

```
dt %>% mutate(New.Date.month = as.Date(Date), rn1 = row_number()) %>% 
  slice(rep(rn1, months))%>%
  group_by(Customer, rn1) %>%
  mutate(New.Date.month = seq(first(Date), by="1 month", length.out=n()))
```

```
  Customer months Date       Cost  New.Date.month   rn1
  <chr>     <dbl> <date>     <chr> <date>         <int>
1 a             2 2014-03-01 100   2014-03-01         1
2 a             2 2014-03-01 100   2014-04-01         1
3 a             2 2015-10-01 200   2015-10-01         2
4 a             2 2015-10-01 200   2015-11-01         2
5 b             2 2015-01-01 50    2015-01-01         3
6 b             2 2015-01-01 50    2015-02-01         3
7 b             3 2016-01-01 20    2016-01-01         4
8 b             3 2016-01-01 20    2016-02-01         4
9 b             3 2016-01-01 20    2016-03-01         4
>
```

However, I am looking to group the customer and increase the "New.Date.Month" by 1 month increments...so my desired output would look like

```
  Customer months Date       Cost  New.Date.month   rn1
  <chr>     <dbl> <date>     <chr> <date>         <int>
1 a             2 2014-03-01 100   2014-03-01         1
2 a             2 2014-03-01 100   2014-04-01         1
3 a             2 2015-10-01 200   2014-05-01         2
4 a             2 2015-10-01 200   2014-06-01         2
5 b             2 2015-01-01 50    2015-01-01         3
6 b             2 2015-01-01 50    2015-02-01         3
7 b             3 2016-01-01 20    2015-03-01         4
8 b             3 2016-01-01 20    2015-04-01         4
9 b             3 2016-01-01 20    2015-05-01         4
```

I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

We need to remove the 'rn1' from the `group_by` step

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>% 
   mutate(New.Date.month = as.Date(Date), rn1 = row_number()) %>% 
   slice(rep(rn1, months))%>%
   group_by(Customer) %>% 
   mutate(New.Date.month = seq(first(New.Date.month), by="1 month", length.out=n()))
# A tibble: 9 x 6
# Groups:   Customer [2]
#  Customer months Date      Cost  New.Date.month   rn1
#  <chr>     <dbl> <chr>     <chr> <date>         <int>
#1 a             2 2014-03-1 100   2014-03-01         1
#2 a             2 2014-03-1 100   2014-04-01         1
#3 a             2 2015-10-1 200   2014-05-01         2
#4 a             2 2015-10-1 200   2014-06-01         2
#5 b             2 2015-01-1 50    2015-01-01         3
#6 b             2 2015-01-1 50    2015-02-01         3
#7 b             3 2016-01-1 20    2015-03-01         4
#8 b             3 2016-01-1 20    2015-04-01         4
#9 b             3 2016-01-1 20    2015-05-01         4
```

---

Can be simplified with `uncount` (without creating a 'rn1' column)

```
library(tidyr)
dt %>% 
  uncount(months) %>% 
  group_by(Customer) %>%
  mutate(New.Date.month = seq(as.Date(first(Date)),
             by = "1 month", length.out = n()))
# A tibble: 9 x 4
# Groups:   Customer [2]
#  Customer Date      Cost  New.Date.month
#  <chr>    <chr>     <chr> <date>        
#1 a        2014-03-1 100   2014-03-01    
#2 a        2014-03-1 100   2014-04-01    
#3 a        2015-10-1 200   2014-05-01    
#4 a        2015-10-1 200   2014-06-01    
#5 b        2015-01-1 50    2015-01-01    
#6 b        2015-01-1 50    2015-02-01    
#7 b        2016-01-1 20    2015-03-01    
#8 b        2016-01-1 20    2015-04-01    
#9 b        2016-01-1 20    2015-05-01
```

---

Also, as the initial dataset is `data.table`, we can use `data.table` approach as well

```
library(data.table)
dt[rep(seq_len(.N), months)][,  New.Date.month := seq(as.Date(Date)[1],
     by = "1 month", length.out = .N), Customer][]
```